# cut eps picture in texshop

Tags: eps

I'm working with a MAC and after compiling with XeLatex the eps pictures included in the file appear to be cut on the left. Anyone knows how to solve this ? 
This is the preamble of the file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\usepackage[toc]{appendix}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\font\fiverm=cmr10 scaled 700

\input pictex.tex
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: If you are using `xetex` do not specify `[dvips]` (just use no option at all so the right back end code is automatically chosen)

Comment: If you are including eps, why is  `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}` set not to include eps extension?

Comment: You can delete the non-latex font declaration and plain input `\font\fiverm=cmr10 scaled 700
\input pictex.tex` and use `\usepackage{pictex}` (which does the same thing, but with latex syntax, and using a 5pt font for `\fiverm` rather than 7pt.)